# Spring boot 3.0.6 Restart endpoint removed?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I'm upgrading my springboot app from springboot 2.7.6 to 3.0.6, I can't reconfigure my restart actuator endpoint. I make sure it's enabled by setting management.endpoint.shutdown.enabled=true

I couldn't find this api in the documentation neither : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.0.6/actuator-api/htmlsingle/#overview

Does it mean it was removed in springboit 3.0.6 ?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot does not have a restart actuator endpoint. Spring Cloud provides this feature in addition to [a few other actuator endpoints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/docs/4.0.3/reference/html/#endpoints).

> I make sure it's enabled by setting management.endpoint.shutdown.enabled=true

The shutdown endpoint is provided by Spring Boot.